# Is this a good result for normal equations,if not how do I know it's good for data set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, normalization, linear-regression

I'm trying to learn normal equations for ML but I'm not sure this result are correct.Parameters are so high and I cannot find hypothesis for this parameters, here is what I mean:

Data set:

```
2104,5,1,45,460
1416,3,2,40,232
1534,3,2,30,315
852,2,1,36,178
```

When I run code I'm taking parameters (theta)

```
[4.74289062e+02  1.65405273e-01  -4.68750000e+00  -1.16445312e+02
 -2.13281250e+00]
```

but these numbers are so high. Is this normal? Also, last line in my code, I tried to print hypothesis just for my first data set elements (2104,5,1,45,460), but it's giving to me an error like this:

```
print (q[0]*x[0][0])+(q[1]*x[0][1])+(q[2]*x[0][2])+(q[3]*x[0][3])+(q[4]*x[0][4])
  IndexError: index out of bounds
```

My code:

```
data = np.loadtxt('bib', delimiter=',');
x=data[:,0:4];
y=data[:,4];
a=np.ones(shape=(y.size,x[0].size+1));
a[:,1:5]=x;
A=np.linalg.inv(a.transpose().dot(a));
B=np.dot(a.transpose(),y);
q=A.dot(a.transpose()).dot(y);
##print (q[0]*x[0][0])+(q[1]*x[0][1])+(q[2]*x[0][2])+(q[3]*x[0][3])+(q[4]*x[0][4])
```

I did not satisfied with these results. How can I make sure these results are true and how should I find my hypothesis with these parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but these numbers are so high. Is this normal?

Your data is not normalized/scaled, your values are big (~1e2) thus coefficients of regressions are the same.

> I tried to print hypothesis just for my first data set elements (2104,5,1,45,460), but it's giving to me an error like this:

Error is reasonable - your data has **4** dimensions, and you try to index 5 values. As you used 1 column of "a" as bias terms, your hypothesis is of form:

```
h(x) = <q, [1 x]> = q0 + q1*x0 + q2*x1 + q3*x2 + q4*x3
```

consequently in code (using your notation and convention):

```
def h(x):
   a = np.ones(x.shape[0], x.shape[1] + 1)
   a[:, 1:5] = x
   return a.dot(q)
```

> How can I make sure these results are true

You can compare them with dozens of existing implementations. You can also create a dummy test set, where y **is** actually a linear combination of x, and check if you get 0 error.